# WebSocketServer MSDN Example

Tags: c#, websocket, msdn

I wrote a simple WebSocketServer, which I found out on the MSDN web-site. But it doesn't work. Can you explain me how I should to run this simple project, because I launch it but nothing happened.

Server

```
namespace WebSocketServer
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = Run();
       // Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static async Task Run()
    {
        HttpListener s = new HttpListener();
        s.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8000/ws");
        s.Start();

        var hc = await s.GetContextAsync();
        if (!hc.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            hc.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            hc.Response.Close();
            return;
        }
        var wsc = await hc.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
        var ws = wsc.WebSocket;

        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        {
           // await Task.Delay(20);
            var time = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(time);
            var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
            await ws.SendAsync(segment, System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Done", CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

}

Client

```
namespace WebSocketClient
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientTask1 = Client();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

   static async Task Client()
    {
        ClientWebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        var uri = new Uri("ws://localhost:8000/ws/");

        await ws.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);

            var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);

            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InvalidMessageType, "I don't do binary", CancellationToken.None);
                return;
            }

            int count = result.Count;
            while (!result.EndOfMessage)
            {
                if (count >= buffer.Length)
                {
                    await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InvalidPayloadData, "That's too long", CancellationToken.None);
                    return;
                }

                segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, count, buffer.Length - count);
                result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);
                count += result.Count;
            }

            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);
            Console.WriteLine(">" + message);
        }

    }
}
}
```

And I need to create a simple web-site, which will be take some data (For example Time) from WebSocketServer and show it on this page. I wrote some code, but nothing is going on

```
<html>
<body>
<script type ="text/javascript">

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/");
ws.onmessage = function (args)
{
  var time = args.data;
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? (the HTTP.SYS required for web-sockets is win-8 upwards and similar server versions) And: are you running as admin? (note : you don't need to run such a server as an admin, but it is a quick way of checking that it isn't a port access ACL issue, since an admin account automatically has access)

Comment: I am using 7 ((( Can I use WebSockets on Windows 7 ?

Comment: yes you can - it is just TCP; however, not using the MS implementation, sadly: " However, the only public implementations of client and server WebSockets are supported on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. "

Comment: I do have a full web-sockets library that I've been meaning to open-source for ages; however, there are a few other open source clients/servers already available

Answer (score 8):

At the server, `Run` is an `async` method; it will return to the caller *as soon as* it reaches the first `await` for which the result is not already completed. That means that your server will exit `Main`, and in the absence of any other primary (non-worker) threads, your server **will terminate**. The `Console.ReadLine` was there for a reason. Put it back:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task1 = Run();
    Console.WriteLine("Press return to exit the server");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```